# Deprecated vs Unsupported SDK

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2

What is the difference between an SDK that is "deprecated" and one that is "unsupported"?

I am asking in the context of developing javascript applications for Rally - I was fixing up an old application when I noticed the SDK will become unsupported in under 2 months.  Does this mean the app will no longer work at all when the SDK becomes unsupported? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I know, unsupported means that a function has thrown away and now it is not available. Deprecated, it means that a function is available but at the future will become unsupported. For unsupported/deprecated "things" almost always exists a new version of this with a different name( and maybe different parameters). You must not use deprecated functions or other staff.

Therefore, check for available updates and upgrades for your SDK, to make sure that your app will keep running and check for other implementations of the things that you are using.

Comment: To add to this, unsupported means that you cannot find support for the software. In this case you would be unable to ask Rally any questions about how it works via a support case

Comment: I figured that much, but I am still wondering - will the apps written using the old SDK/API work at all?

Comment: If you are using deprecated SDK, yes, app will work. But you can search for new staff that guarantee that your app will work for a long period of time. Another issue is that a function may be deprecated but because a lot of applications and frameworks use this function the company continue to support the function for a long time (maybe years). It is not easy for big apps to change their code...

Comment: They will work for a while but I would recommend using the newest versions for any new projects. We have plans to reach out to people before we turn off any versions of the API